# JQuery event not responding after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm designing a faceted search and I have a simple ul block.  Each list item has a different data value and I want to respond when a list item with a data value of '6000003' is clicked. The code below works, but not after the data is refreshed with an AJAX call.

After the AJAX call I still have a list item with a data value of '6000003' but it does not respond to the click.

```
<ul class='refine_checkbox'>
    <li class='refine_checkbox' data-val='24000022'>List Item 1</li>
    <li class='refine_checkbox' data-val='24000023'>List Item 2</li>
    <li class='refine_checkbox' data-val='6000003'>List Item 3</li>
</ul>

$('li[data-val="6000003"]').click(function(){ 
    // Do something 
});
```

I think I might need to attach an event handler so I looked at the Jquery.on() function and tried this but it does not work:

```
$('li[data-val="6000003"]').on('click', 'li', function(){ 
    // Do something 
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could give a unique id that would be awsome. 
For now try something like this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li[data-val="6000003"]', function(){ 
// Do something 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to use `.on()` when delegating is:

```
$('.refine_checkbox').on('click', 'li[data-val=600003]', function(){ 
    // Do something 
});
```

You bind the handler to the static element, and specify the dynamic selector in the arguments.

Comment: This works as long as refine_checkbox is not being replaced in the update.

Comment: True. I'm assuming that he's just adding and removing `LI`s, or changing their `data-value`.

Comment: Barmar's code doesn't work for me because, as Paul surmised, I am replacing the whole refine_checkbox <ul>.  How should I proceed?

Comment: I explained the general approach in my answer: bind to the nearest static element that will always contain the dynamic elements.

Comment: @monkey64, for example, I didn't know what you were replacing, so in my answer, I put it on the `body`.

Comment: That will work, but I always recommend binding it as tightly as possible. Binding to `body` means that every click will have to run a handler to check whether the target is this `LI`. You can also run into subtle bugs if you have other click handlers that use `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because new `li` elements are being added, but no click handler is added.

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'li[data-val="6000003"]', function(){ 
    // Do something 
});
```